# Cannot navigate by typing the state's name in browser's url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
mainApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

$stateProvider
.state('page', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/newgmr/admin',
    views: {
        'home': {
            template:  '<div ui-view="body"></div>'
        }
    }
}).state('page.login', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        'body@page': {
            templateUrl:  'mainApp/landingPage/login.html',
            controller:   'loginController'
        }
    }
})
.state('page.forgotpassword', {
    url: '/forgot-password',
    views: {
        'body@page': {
            templateUrl:  'mainApp/landingPage/forgotPassword.html',
            controller:   'forgotPasswordController'
        }
    }
})
.state('page.resetpassword', {
    url: '/reset',
    views: {
        'body@page': {
            templateUrl:  'mainApp/landingPage/resetPage.html',
            controller:   'resetPasswordController'
        }
    }
})
.state('admin.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        'header@admin': {
            templateUrl: 'mainApp/dashboardPage/header.html'
        },
        'leftPane@admin': {
            templateUrl: 'mainApp/dashboardPage/leftPane.html',
            controller : 'leftSidePaneController'
        },
        'body@admin': {
            templateUrl: 'mainApp/dashboardPage/tabHolder.html'
        },
        'footer@admin': {
            templateUrl: 'mainApp/dashboardPage/footer.html'
        }
    }
});

$urlRouterProvider.
otherwise('/');
```

I am newbie to angular. When I give, localhost/newgmr/admin it loads my app. But when I try to navigate to any other state, say forgot-password screen by typing localhost/newgmr/admin/forgot-password into the browser's url and hit enter, the app shows 404 page. However, I can achieve this by clicking on a link which will call the state "page.forgotpassword". I understand that this happens because there is no actual directory like forgot-password and there is no index.html in that location either. So, please help me how to achieve this. User must be able to navigate to a state by typing the url as well.

If the data provided is not enough, please let me know.

Comment: How are you hosting the app? Does the server have a wildcard to handle any URL via a single page? i.e. all requests go to index.html unless found in path.

Comment: You have enabled html5 mode.  just remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});`

Comment: @Nandeep, I did not understand the question. To be frank, I am not doing the server side for this application. I am hosting the app in linux machine, ie, I have put the app folder in my var/www/html location in ubuntu.

Comment: @ebinmanuval, yes, that was helpful, but then now, a # appears in the url

Comment: if your are using apache then  add .htaccess file in your root folder to enable html5 mode reffer https://gist.github.com/jxnblk/6137537

Comment: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113909/discussion-between-jayaraj-ps-and-ebinmanuval).

Comment: The purpose of the $stateProvider is for navigating via AngularJS, not via typing it directly into the url. So for example you have a link from admin like so: <a ui-sref="page.forgotpassword">Forgot password</a> then angularjs will take that and navigate according to what you have in your $stateProvider.state('page.forgotpassword', {}) (for example)